# oracle to_date conversion showing literal does not match string format

Tags: oracle

If I use a converter for unixtime I get

Tue, 31 May 2005 16:23:17 GMT for 1117556597. If I run the below query, I get the error 
literal does not match string format. Why is that?

```
select to_date('1117556597','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS') from dual
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TO_DATE` method tries to match the input with the provided pattern. For ex:

```
TO_DATE('2003/07/09', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
TO_DATE('070903', 'MMDDYY')
TO_DATE('20020315', 'yyyymmdd')
```

you can check http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm

I guess this will help you (haven't tested)

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + 
( 1117556597/ (1000*60 * 60 * 24) ),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "DATE" FROM DUAL ;
```

Answer (score 1):

**19700101 is January 1, 1970. This is the "epoch" for UNIX systems. UNIX systems keep track of time by counting the number of seconds since the "epoch".**

You need to `convert` it like this,

```
SQL> SELECT TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd')  + (1117556597/24/60/60) thedate
  2  FROM dual
  3  /

THEDATE
---------
31-MAY-05
```

Lets see the complete `datetime`,

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd')  + (1117556597/24/60/60),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') thedate
  2  FROM dual
  3  /

THEDATE
--------------------
31-MAY-2005 16:23:17

SQL>
```

**EDIT** Regarding the `TIMEZONE`

It is better to explicitly mention the timezone.

You could mention the timezone in the literal itself, or cast it as `UTC` and convert it to your `local timezone`.

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR (
    FROM_TZ (
      CAST (DATE '1970-01-01 + (1117556597/24/60/60) AS TIMESTAMP),
      'UTC')
    AT TIME ZONE 'your local timezone',
  'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM dual;
```

**NOTE** Please check syntax, I don't have DB access while making this edit.

Comment: you have marked the other answer as correct, however, that is not correct since it converts the 1000th of a second too. In your case, `60 * 60 * 24` is what you need.

Comment: Please note, Unix "epoch" refers to UTC time. Perhaps you have to do some corrections to your local timezone.