# Number to Date in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have a number column where date is stored as epoch unix timestamp in millisec like (1406851200000).
How can i use this value to compare the date against another column where date is stored in TIMESTAMP(6) format.

I searched a lot. But not able to figure out the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13914579/330315

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26711372/3989608