# Convert LDAP Date in SQL (milliseconds to nanoseconds)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

I am getting date in `milliseconds` format.

i.e.: `1427342400000 is essentially 3/26/2015`.

Now I want to further convert date in `nanoseconds` and pass this value in accountexpires attribute in Active Directory.

What is the query to convert milliseconds date to nanoseconds date?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to further convert date in nanoseconds

Ok, but convert to nano seconds since when? Looking at your example, I assume the start point to be `'01-JAN-1970'`.

If I want to **convert a date to milliseconds** since `01-JAN-1970`, I would do this:

```
SQL> SELECT to_number(SYSDATE - to_date('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) milliseconds
  2  FROM dual;

        MILLISECONDS
--------------------
       1424428022000

SQL>
```

Now,

> 1 millisecond = 1000000 nanosecond

, using this formula, just **multiply it to the difference of the date**.

**Convert a date to nanoseconds:**

```
SQL> SELECT to_number(SYSDATE - to_date('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000000) nanoseconds
  2  FROM dual;

         NANOSECONDS
--------------------
 1424428111000000000

SQL>
```

**To convert it back to date:**

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(to_date('1970-01-01 00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24')
  2         +
  3        (1424428111000000000 )/1000000/1000/60/60/24 , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS am') nano_to_date
  4  FROM dual;

NANO_TO_DATE
----------------------
2015-02-20 10:28:31 am

SQL>
```

**UPDATE** Regarding the `TIMEZONE`

It is better to explicitly mention the timezone.

You could mention the timezone in the literal itself, or cast it as `UTC` and convert it to your `local timezone`.

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26711372/3989608).

Comment: Consider Unix epoch is 1970:01:01 00:00:00 **UTC**! It may differ from your local time zone.

Comment: Yes, agreed. OP just wanted to know to convert date to nanoseconds, so I didn't pay much attention to adding the timezone. I already answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26711372/3989608. Anyway , I will edit my answer and add this link

Answer (score 0):

When you say "1427342400000 is essentially 3/26/2015", it looks like a Unix timestamp.

According my findings the LDAP timestamp is

**The number of 100-nanoseconds intervals since `1601-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`.**

And a Unix timestamp is

**The number of seconds (sometimes milliseconds are used) since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`.**

I assume you get a Unix timestamp and you want to convert to a LDAP timestamp.
This function should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ConvertTime(unixTimestamp IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
    timestampUTC TIMESTAMP;
    theInterval INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND(9);
    epoche NUMBER;
BEGIN

    -- Convert Unix Timestamp-Number to TIMESTAMP:
    timestampUTC := (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' + unixTimestamp * (INTERVAL '1' SECOND / 1000));

    -- Convert TIMESTAMP to LDAP Timestamp-Number 
    theInterval := timestampUTC - TIMESTAMP '1601-01-01 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
    epoche := EXTRACT(DAY FROM theInterval)*24*60*60 
        + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM theInterval)*60*60 
        + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM theInterval)*60 
        + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM theInterval);
    RETURN ROUND(epoche * 1e9/100);

END ConvertTime;


SELECT TO_CHAR(ConvertTime(1427342400000), 'fm999999999999999999999') FROM dual;

130718108400000000
```

**Update:**

You can to it much sorter:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR((1427342400000/1000 + (DATE '1970-01-01' - DATE '1601-01-01')*24*60*60) * (1e9/100), 'fm999999999999999999999') AS LDAP_TS
FROM dual;

130718160000000000
```

**However**, you get a difference of 5160 seconds (86 Minutes) but I don't have any idea why you get this. For an interval between 2 dates the time zone should have no influence.