# Converting NUMBER to DATE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a numeric field in my Oracle database that represents the date.

I'm not so familiar with Oracle commands.

I was wondering if anyone could provide some guide here.

Thanks.

example: 1435755908 = 7/1/2015 9:05

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert LDAP Date in SQL (milliseconds to nanoseconds)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620762/convert-ldap-date-in-sql-milliseconds-to-nanoseconds)

Comment: As an epoch time that translates as 2015-07-01 13:05:08, so you have to think about the time zone too I guess; that value represents an EST time?

Comment: correct  this is EST time

Answer (score 1):

This is a Unix Timestamp, i.e. the seconds since January 1970, try this formula:

```
timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + 1435755908/86400
```

Comment: This is the output that I got:"01-JUL-2015 13:05:08"

Answer (score 1):

Since there seems to be a time zone difference:

```
select date '1970-01-01' + 1435755908/86400 as converted from dual;

CONVERTED                              
----------------------------------------
2015-07-01 13:05:08
```

you seem to need to do some time zone manipulation. Epoch times are UTC so you can use `from_tz` to declare that, and then `at time zone` to get the US/East Coast equivalent:

```
select from_tz(cast(date '1970-01-01' + 1435755908/86400 as timestamp), 'UTC')
  at time zone 'America/New_York' as converted from dual;

CONVERTED                              
----------------------------------------
2015-07-01 09:05:08.000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
```

Which is a time stamp with time zone. If you want it as a plain date then cast it:

```
select cast(from_tz(cast(date '1970-01-01' + 1435755908/86400 as timestamp), 'UTC')
  at time zone 'America/New_York' as date) as converted from dual;

CONVERTED                              
----------------------------------------
2015-07-01 09:05:08
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast replay. I don't have from_tz converter option.

Comment: @angus - it's a built-in function; not sure when it was introduced but at least 10g. What Oracle version are you using?